# WCF methods and architecture question

Tags: wcf

I have a very data intensive, in-memory WCF application written. When it starts, it loads a lot of data and waits for the client to call its functions. Right now the data loading and the calculation function are in one WCF. I'm trying to separate the "load data" and "calculation" pieces into two WCF so that whenever I start the calculation I don't have to wait 10-20 minutes so that the "load data" functions are done. Since I'm separating the load data piece I have to expose everything through the data/service contracts as a function, but the load data classes have a lot of methods that get used and I may have to use those methods on the client side ("calculation" side). Since I believe that methods cannot be passed to the client so that the client can't call the method, what do you think I should do?

I'm trying to make the 2 WCFs function like a one WCF so that all the methods get called, but separating this into two WCF makes these methods inaccessible to the client right?

Scenario is. 1. Load data 2. Calculation loads individual data from load data WCF service. 3. Calculation calls functions on the received data (this is not possible?).

Should I use remoting, shared library? Make each of the methods inside the contracts separate service calls?

Any insight is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than loading all data in one go, you can load data as and when required by the code. This will improve your turn around time and you dont even need to seperate your existing code